# Element clicked on from group with same class

Tags: jquery, html, targeting

I have the following menu

```
<ul>
   <li class="button">One</li>
   <li class="button">Two</li>
   <li class="button">Three</li>
   <li class="button">Four</li>
   <li class="button">Five</li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide only the button that I click on, currently my code is hiding all buttons.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".button").hide( "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

The `this` jQuery selector will select the element that sent the function call, in this case the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the event handler `this` will refer to the clicked element, if you select `this` with jQuery you can call the `hide` function:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```